# chronograf: Not able to add default influxDB connection when using OAuth 2.0

Tags: influxdb, chronograf

I configured Chronograph to use generic OAuth 2.0 (using cloud foundry UAA). Users authentication works fine but the problem is that the default influxdb connection is not taken into consideration. In fact this configuration works:

```
chronograf  --log-level="debug" --resources-path="/usr/share/chronograf/resources" --influxdb-url="http://influxDB.log.database:8086" --influxdb-username="usename" --influxdb-password="pass"
```

here is the content of `/usr/share/chronograf/resources` folder:

**influxdb.src:**

```
{
  "id": "9999",
  "name": "MyInfluxDB",
  "username": "user1,
  "password": "password1",
  "url": "http://influxDB.log.database:8086",
  "type": "influx",
  "insecureSkipVerify": true,
  "default": true,
  "telegraf": "telegraf.autogen",
  "organization": "Default"
}
```

Both connections are automatically created when *chronoraf* starts :

- MyInfluxDB
- http://influxDB.log.database:8086

but When I run chronograf with the following options (To use **OAuth 2.0** and create an **influxdb connection**) :

```
export TOKEN_SECRET="token_secret"; export JWKS_URL="https://uaa/token_keys"; export PUBLIC_URL="http://chronograf:8888"; chronograf  --log-level="debug" --resources-path="/usr/share/chronograf/resources" --generic-name="generic" --generic-client-id="id" --generic-client-secret="secret" --generic-scopes="openid" --generic-auth-url="https://uaa/oauth/authorize" --generic-token-url="https://uaa/oauth/token" --generic-api-url="https://uaa/userinfo"
```

The OAuth 2.0 works fine but once redirected to the **chronograf** dashboard I cannot see the connections and even when I created a connection manually and I log in I cannot found any connection that is created automatically on startup as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

the field `organization` needs an id. The `id` for the `Default` orginization uses a lower case `d`. If you change your src file to,

```
{
  "id": "9999",
   "name": "MyInfluxDB",
   "username": "user1,
   "password": "password1",
   "url": "http://influxDB.log.database:8086",
   "type": "influx",
   "insecureSkipVerify": true,
   "default": true,
   "telegraf": "telegraf.autogen",
   "organization": "default"
}
```

It should now work.

you can see where the id is defined in their source here https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/blob/9d8a49ba0ef8131cdce22d73718859f55f434db2/bolt/organizations.go#L20